# while filling tha data grid view taking long time and system getting hang

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

in my windows for i have a data grid view..i am filling data grid view like this:

```
Sub filldgv()
        Try


        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Tbarcode", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("PlateNo", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("DelEcode", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("KRRT", GetType(Integer))
        dt.Columns.Add("DT", GetType(Integer))



        DGVReleased.DataSource = dt
        DGVReleased.Columns(0).Width = 120
        DGVReleased.Columns(1).Width = 65
        DGVReleased.Columns(2).Width = 65
        DGVReleased.Columns(3).Width = 60
        DGVReleased.Columns(4).Width = 60
        ' Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Populate(dt))
        Dim bgw = New BackgroundWorker()
        AddHandler bgw.DoWork, Sub() Populate(dt)
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub Populate(ByVal dt As DataTable)

        Try


        Using reader As TextReader = File.OpenText("C:\Program Files\IBS\login.txt")
            txtvalue = Integer.Parse(reader.ReadLine())

        End Using
        Glocid = txtvalue
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("IBS_fetchreqVehicleinPodium")

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = con.connect
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Glocid

        Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            DGVReleased.AutoGenerateColumns = True

            Dim o = {dr("TBarcode").ToString(),
                     dr("PlateNo").ToString(),
                     dr("DelEcode").ToString(),
                     If(IsDBNull(dr("KRRT")), 0, dr("KRRT")),
                     If(IsDBNull(dr("DT")), 0, dr("DT"))}

            dt.Rows.Add(o)
        End While


        dr.Close()
        con.disconnect()
            changecolor()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

i have button in my form
then i will call **filldgv** method in my button click event..when ever the data inside the grid view more than 100 then i press my button its taking long time to load the data and  application getting hang ...
how i can resolve this issue.. 
any help is very appriciable?

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the Try-Catches since you are just swallowing the exceptions and actually try fixing the bugs.  You can't access the GUI controls in your DoWork method, it's running on a different thread.

Comment: so where i have to change my code here..

Comment: Are you looking to have the whole DataTable filled and *then* loaded into the grid, or have the grid show some rows as they are being filled?

Comment: sir i am not caring about filling the grid view..i dont want to hang my system while filling the grid view..while clicking button some time application is hanging..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the DataTable is the source of your DataGridView, every time you add a row, it's updating the DataGridView control, so you are getting very little benefit of using that thread.

Try adding the RunWorkerCompleted event of your BackgroundWorker and setting the DataSource of the DataGridView at that time:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Tbarcode", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("PlateNo", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("DelEcode", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("KRRT", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("DT", GetType(Integer))

Dim bgw As New BackgroundWorker()
AddHandler bgw.DoWork, Sub() Populate(dt)
AddHandler bgw.RunWorkerCompleted, Sub()
                                     DGVReleased.AutoGenerateColumns = True
                                     DGVReleased.DataSource = dt
                                     DGVReleased.Columns(0).Width = 120
                                     DGVReleased.Columns(1).Width = 65
                                     DGVReleased.Columns(2).Width = 65
                                     DGVReleased.Columns(3).Width = 60
                                     DGVReleased.Columns(4).Width = 60
                                   End Sub
bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
```

You should notice that I moved your `DGVReleased.AutoGenerateColumns = True` setting from your while...loop in the Populate method.  Background threads should not be accessing GUI controls.

I would also avoid empty Try-Catch branches.  Silently eating the exception will hide anything going wrong in your code, and as a programmer, you want to know what's going wrong.

Comment: so this code i have to write in RunWorkerCompleted event of your BackgroundWorker